# how transpose imported key animation?

Tags: animation

I have 2 animations of the same object I try to merge in one. the problem is that each start at the same origin XYZ and I need the second one to in the continuity of the first one.

What I did so far is to open the 2nd animation, copy the keyframes from the graph editor, open the first one, go the last keyframes of its animation and paste in the graph editor the keyframes.

When I hit play I see the first animation playing and when the 1st keyframe of the 2nd animation start the object is "teleported" to the origin XYZ.
 I have no clue how to move the 2nd animation without having to redo each keyframe of it which would be a nightmare .

How do I do that?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Render both anims and use VSE. Second strip starts where the first one ends. Render it and its done.

Comment: Sorry I should have explained that  the goal is to merge both animation to export them after as a fbx not to generate a rendering. I saw that if I switch to pose mode, i can keyframe by keyframe repostion the object to be in the continiuty of the first animation... but there must be a simplier way to select all keyframe and modify the XYZ reference coordinate to transpose it?